# create a new request in downlaoder middleware

Tags: scrapy

How can I create a new request with my proxy settings active
middlewares.py

```py
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
    from scrapy.http import Request
    def get_url(url):
        payload = {'api_key': 'my_api', 'url': url}
        proxy_url = 'http://api.scraperapi.com/?'+urlencode(payload)
        return proxy_url
    
    class MyCustomDownloader:
    
        def process_request(self, request, spider):
            url = request.url
            return Request(url=get_url(url))
    
        def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
            return response
```

settings.py

```py
    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
        'usr157.middlewares.MyCustomDownloader': 543,
    }
```

spider.py

```py
    class testSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'test'
        start_urls = ['http://httpbin.org/ip']
        def parse(self, response):
            print(response.text)
```

when I run `scrapy crawl test` it gets stuck with not 1 request being made, Ideally what I want is 1 request with my modified URL using `get_url` function

Comment: Change `Request` to `request.replace`. That creates a new request that is identical to `request` except for the specified changes. It’s @georgiy’s approach, but with working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I see you want to use `scraperapi` proxy.
This proxy has its own API to work with it.
This is an example from official page https://www.scraperapi.com/documentation

```py
# remember to install the library: pip install scraperapi-sdk
from scraper_api import ScraperAPIClient
client = ScraperAPIClient('YOURAPIKEY')
result = client.get(url = 'http://httpbin.org/ip').text
print(result);
# Scrapy users can simply replace the urls in their start_urls and parse function
# Note for Scrapy, you should not use DOWNLOAD_DELAY and
# RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY, these will lower your concurrency and are not
# needed with our API

# ...other scrapy setup code
start_urls =[client.scrapyGet(url = 'http://httpbin.org/ip')]
def parse(self, response):

# ...your parsing logic here
yield scrapy.Request(client.scrapyGet(url = 'http://httpbin.org/ip'), self.parse)
```

to work with middleware you need to male simple changes like this:

```py
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    if 'api.scraperapi' not in request.url:
        new_url = 'http://api.scraperapi.com/?api_key=YOURAPIKEY&url=' + request.url
        request = request.replace(url=new_url)
        return request
    else:
        return None
```

PS: don't have `scraperapi` account to test it properly.

Comment: it doesn't work, it crashes in the when I run it ( PS there is a free trial version on it)

Comment: pls check now :) answer updated and tested, works fine every time different IP

Comment: what error? because I tested it locally and no errors appeared and I received new IP for every request

Answer (score 0):

in your implementation there is no callback in your generated request.

On most of scrapy middlewares [source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/tree/master/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares) ([1](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/httpauth.py), [2](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/defaultheaders.py), [3](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/httpproxy.py)) - their `process_request` method doesn't return new request object. They modify parameters of original request:

```
def process_request(self, request, spider)
    request.url=get_url(url)
```

Comment: did you try your answer?

Comment: it gives me `AttributeError: Request.url is not modifiable, use Request.replace() instead`